# UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal flipSideView always at top

Tags: iphone

I want a flipSideView that takes up just the middle part of the screen.
Normally when you do this, it flips the entire iphone screen back and forth.
I thought that if I created a smaller container view and made a flipside for that, it would just flip the size of that view. (kinda like in the itunes app when you choose to listen to a sample of a song and the little button on the left flips over).

The problem I'm having is that even though I have a container which is smaller than the 320X480, when I flip it still uses the entire screen.

I'm using the method just like the default 'utility' application.
I've tried moving the view into place when it flips, but it doesnt help

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

figured it out.
I just need to change the center of each view in these spots

```
// called when the flipside is dismissed by a button
- (void)flipSideViewControllerDidFinish:(FlipSideViewController *)controller {

    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    self.view.center=CGPointMake(self.view.center.x, self.view.frame.size.height/2+44);
}

// called when the button is pressed to flip
- (IBAction)showFlipSide:(id)sender 
{    
    [self presentModalViewController:listView animated:YES];    
    listView.view.center=CGPointMake(listView.view.center.x, listView.view.frame.size.height/2+44);
}
```